# Reaching an S3 location on AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an AWS lambda function which needs to reach a file in S3 bucket, my setup looks like this:

```
#lambda function

def test(event=None, context=None):
    item = 'https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/bucket/file.json'
    print(item)
```

When I run it I get:

> "errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/bucket/file.json'"

I've tried using this path as well:

```
s3://bucket/file.json
```

**EDIT**

Adding the actual code:

```
df = None
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'arn:aws:s3:::gadsinfo/client_secrets.json'
VIEW_ID = '111'

def test(event=None, context=None):
    def initialize_analyticsreporting():
        '''Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.

        Returns:
        An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
        '''
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
            KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

        # Build the service object.
        analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

        return analytics
```

The error message

> File "/var/task/test.py", line 21, in initialize_analyticsreporting
>       KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)
>     File "/var/task/oauth2client/service_account.py", line 219, in from_json_keyfile_name
>       with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj:
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'arn:aws:s3:::gadsinfo/client_secrets.json'

The line 21 is the `credentials = ...` line.

But get the same error message. How can I find the file in S3?

Comment: Is your Lambda allowed to reach the S3 Bucket?

Comment: That is a good question, when I go to permission I see that I have created a service role for the function. Not sure how I would be able to check what permissions it has. How could I check that?

Comment: Your error message does not match the code. The code you show merely sets and prints a variable. It would not generate the error you show. Please identify which line is actually generating the error and show it in the Question.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I've added the actual code part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name()` call is expecting to be provided with a **filename on the local disk**, not a reference to an Amazon S3 object.

If the Lambda function has been given sufficient permissions via its IAM Role, it could first **download that file to the local disk**:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.download_file('gadsinfo', 'client_secrets.json', '/tmp/client_secrets.json')

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
            '/tmp/client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
```

Comment: Okay, I understood that a file in S3 is the same as in local machine. But when I run the code I am getting the following error: `Syntax error in module 'test': invalid syntax (_base.py, line 414)`. Do you have an idea what may cause it?

Comment: You'll need to figure out which line is causing the error. (eg What is on line 414?) It appears you are using 3rd-party code, so it might be difficult to debug.